# persisting a session causes detached entity passed to persist error

Tags: hibernate

I have the the below posted two hibernate classes, and i am trying to insert records into TestAuthor table using the code mentioned in populateAuthorTable method which is posted below as well.
when i run the code i receive

```
detached entity passed to persist: msc.hibernate.persistence.TestAuthor
```

please let me know how to solve this error

**populateAuthorTable**:

```
private void populateAuthorTable() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    ArrayList<TestAuthor> authorsList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Long i = (long) 0; i < 30; i++) {
        authorsList.add(new TestAuthor(i, "FName_" + i, "LName_" + i));
    }

    int i = 0;
    for (TestAuthor ta : authorsList) {
        session.persist(ta);
        i++;
    }
}
```

**TestAuthor**:

```
@Entity 
@Table(schema = "afk_owner", name = "testauthor")
public class TestAuthor {

@Id
@Column(name = "authorid")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequencegen")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequencegen", sequenceName = "afk_owner.testauthor_seq", allocationSize = 1)
private Long mAuthorID;

@Column(name = "FNAME")
private String mFName;

@Column(name = "LNAME")
private String mLName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<TestBook> booksList;

public Long getmAuthorID() {
    return mAuthorID;
}

public List<TestBook> getBooksList() {
    return booksList;
}

public void setBooksList(List<TestBook> booksList) {
    this.booksList = booksList;
}

public void setmAuthorID(Long mAuthorID) {
    this.mAuthorID = mAuthorID;
}

public String getmFName() {
    return mFName;
}

public void setmFName(String mFName) {
    this.mFName = mFName;
}

public String getmLName() {
    return mLName;
}

public void setmLName(String mLName) {
    this.mLName = mLName;
}

public TestAuthor() {
}

public TestAuthor(Long id, String fName, String lName) {
    this.mAuthorID = id;
    this.mFName = fName;
    this.mLName = lName;
    this.booksList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When you set an @Id field of a new object, hibernate will think it's a detached entity. The point of the sequence generator you've created, is to generate Ids for new entities. Just don't set the Id and it should work. Very rough solution:

```
public TestAuthor(Long id, String fName, String lName) {
    //this.mAuthorID = id;
    this.mFName = fName;
    this.mLName = lName;
    this.booksList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Usually you would get this error when your objects are genuinely detached, not just wrongly initiated fresh ones.